# Given a raster layer and some coordinates, is it possible to somehow get the color value (in HEX or RGB) of that pixel in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster

I just want to get the color value based on some coordinates. 
Is there a plugin that can do the job?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the image composed of 3 bands in RGB color, you can use [Point Sampling Tool Plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJ5d2.png) to extract the RGB values to the point shapefile.

In the example below, I have a shapefile of 2 points, and an image composed of 3 bands: Band 1 (Red), Band 2 (Green), Band 3 (Blue)

[image]

[image]

When using Point Sampling Tool Plugin you need to make sure that **the projection of both point shapefile and the image is same**. It will not work if the projections of both layers are different.

When running Point Sampling Tool Plugin, select the point layer and select the fields that contains the 3 bands mentioned above. Save the output file into your hard disk.

[image]

You can also rename the fields Band 1 (Raser), Band 2 (Raster), Band 3 (Raster) to Red, Green, Blue, respectively, in the `Field` Tab:

[image]

Here is the output:

[image: [1]: https://plugins.qgis.org/plug]